# Capturing and displaying return value from a call to C system()

Tags: c, linux

I am on ubuntu linux 10.04 
I have the following

```
#simplec.c  
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{

    printf("Hello World\n");
    system("ps -H");
    return 12;


}
```

AND

```
#callsimplec.c
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{

    int ret =0;
    ret = system("./simplec");
    printf("In callsimplec ret is %d\n", ret);

}
```

When I do

```
gcc callsimplec.c -o callsimplec
gcc simplec.c -o simplec
./callsimplec
```

I get:

```
Hello World
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
27238 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
28066 pts/2    00:00:00   callsimplec
28067 pts/2    00:00:00     simplec
28068 pts/2    00:00:00       ps
In callsimplec ret is 3072
```

So I figured out that 3072 is printed because 256 times 12 is 3072. Whatever return value I use in simplec.c I get that value multiplied by 256 as the output in print. Why is that? I am just trying to make sense of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value returned by `system` should be used with the macros: WEXITED, WIFEXITSTATUS etc.

The value returned by `system` (and by the `wait` family) is, acording to case:

- Normal termination:

  ```
  15 ............. 8 ............. 0
      exit status         0x00
  ```
- Killed by signal:

  ```
  15 ............. 8 7............ 0
        unused        killer signal
  ```
- Stopped by signal

  ```
  15 ............. 8 ............. 0
      stop signal         0x7f
  ```
- Continued by signal

  ```
  15 ............................. 0
                 0xFFF
  ```

**So in your case the process exited normally and system returned `12` shifted 8 times**.

Comment: More specifically, the return value from `system(3)` is the value returned by [`wait(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait).

Comment: But I still don't understand why left shift the value? I don't get it.

Comment: @abc Because `wait` returns more information than that `12` of yours. Read my answer again.

Comment: What a peculiar design decision.